# Run Excel Macro using VBS

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to run excel macro using command prompt through VBS. Excel file open ups but not able to run macro. The name of Macro as well as module is "Wallet"

While tryig to view macro, it reflects as "PERSONAL.XLSB!WALLET"

Pls help

```
Sub ExcelMacroExample()

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Output\abc.xlsb")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Run "Wallet"
xlApp.Save
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing line `xlApp.Run "Wallet"` to `xlApp.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!WALLET"` and then running the code.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij nope!....its not working

Comment: I just realized that my personal.xlsb is not available in the excel i am trying to run macro. Is there any way I can make this available....?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like that

```
Sub ExcelMacroExample()

    Dim xlApp
    Dim xlBook

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Output\abc.xlsb")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("Path to your Personal.XLSB")
    xlApp.Run "Personal.XLSB!Macro"

    'xlApp.Save                   <= This line would not work, xlApp does not have a Save Method
    'xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close   <= You already have the reference to the workbook. It is xlBook
    xlBook.Close True           ' <= This will save and close the workbook you opened
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you do not know where your `Personal.xlsb` is try the standard location.

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open (xlApp.StartupPath & xlApp.PathSeparator & "Personal.XLSB")
```